# Preference File is Not XML

Tags: macos, plist

I want to modify this file, following PathFinder's instructions

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist
```

however, it's not XML whatsoever. Looks more like some binary format.

What am I missing?

Here are the instructions from the PathFinder manual

> If you’re feeling more geeky, edit the
>   preference file
>   com.apple.loginwindow.plist and add
>   the following lines:

```
<key>Finder</key>  <string>/[path to]/Path Finder.app</string>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has switched to using binary formatted preferences, it's the same format, just represented in a "compressed" binary format, instead of "human readable".

To convert a binary .plist file to XML format for editing, type this in the Terminal:
`plutil -convert xml1 some_file.plist`

To convert an XML .plist file to binary for use:
`plutil -convert binary1 some_other_file.plist`

Comment: Perfect. Someone that seems scarier, but it is, in fact, safer all around.

Comment: It's usually easier to just use an actual Property List editor that can handle all three supported formats.

Answer (score 1):

While Benjamin's answer is indeed correct and does answer your question, I would suggest that the "safer" way to tweak preferences is to use the `defaults` command. Such as

```
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/loginwindow Finder "/path/to/Path Finder.app"
```

Then you don't need to worry whether the plist is binary or XML.

Comment: Wow +1... man I thought I could avoid learning all this stuff, but apparently not.